# Border affects components position java

Tags: java, position, components, border

So I have a JPanel that has an inner border (it's toggled based on MouseEnter/MouseExit, as a sort of a rollover effect). I also have a JLabel. The problem is that the JLabel seems to be positioned relative to the border - not the actual edge of the JPanel. So whenever I move my mouse over the panel, the label shifts over a couple of pixels. I would prefer it to stay stationary.

So I guess my question is, what's the best way to change the border of a panel without affecting the positions of the components inside the panel?

Here's the mouselisteners for the panel:

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setBorder(null);
        }

    });
```

The JLabel is added simply using borderlayout:

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JLabel label = new JLabel("testlabel");
panel.add(label,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an [EmptyBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html) when the bevel border is not in use. Give it the same width/height you would the bevel border.

I don't do a lot of messing around with layouts or their managers but that's what I would try.

**Edit**

Since it seems you may wish to have an overlay type effect instead of a border, you could create a custom JPanel class and include some code in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method to draw this overlay.

Something similar to:

```
public class OverlayBorderJPanel extends JPanel
{
    boolean containsMouse = false; //set to true by mouseListener when contains
    BufferedImage overlay = //you would need to load an image border here, 
                            //rather than having a java created border
                            //You could have alpha so it is half see-through

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (containsMouse)
        {
            g.drawImage(//use 0,0 position with panel width/height)
        }
    }
}
```

I think it would work with something like that, but you may need to call the panel's repaint() method in the listener as well.

Comment: Did that work, or are you going to try it now? Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It's good enough for what I need, not an exact solution though. Now the label is constantly in the shifted position (because the border is always there) - so when I have the invisible border, there's a couple of pixels of empty space between the panel and label. Ideally it would constantly be attached to the side of the panel, and the border would just be painted ontop of the label if it gets in the way.

Comment: My guess is, because your label is within the container, and the container is modifying its border, (or edge), you won't be able to achieve what you want by doing it this way. I'm going to edit my answer with another suggestion, but obviously you can keep it the way you have it now if you prefer not spending some time on it.

Comment: Great, that works =P
As it happens I was already using a custom JPanel and overriding the PaintComponent to set a custom background. So all I had to do was load in a border and paint that as well. I considered manually painting in a border, but I didn't think to actually just load one in from the image.

Comment: Cool, if you didn't like that I would have suggested trying to change the width and height of the panel by a few pixels to compensate for the border, but without trying it, I don't think it would work that well.